# Sails.js Changing content onClick while the cloud action is performed

Tags: vue.js, sails.js

Still a fresh user of `sails.js` I try to make a full website. I get a good experience in `PHP` and under `symfony`. Sadly this is not helping me a lot here.

I try a basic stuff a still don't figure how to do it properly.

I have a cloud action who allow me to remove steam account of my user. While this is perform I want to change the render on the client side to avoid a redirect or an other method.

Has in the plazy course perform by the creator of sails, he show an example using data in an array. He use the lodash function `_.remove(array, id)` and `this.$forupdate();` to reload the data, and so change the content display.

So my problem is that i want to change the text, i try to use the same methode by using `_.remove(this.profile.steamAccount);` since my vue use `v-if='profile.steamAccount'` to display the content.

```js
//// vue.js code

<div class="col-sm-12">Steam :
  <strong v-if='profile.steamAccount' id="steamProfile" class="float-right">{{profile.steamAccount.personaname}} <i @click="clickDeleteSteam(me.steamAccount)" style="color: red;" class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></strong>
  <strong v-else class="float-right"><a href="/auth/steam">Link my steam</a></strong>
</div>

//// page.js 
methods: {

    clickDeleteSteam: async function(steamID){
      await Cloud.deleteSteamAccount.with({id: steamID});
      _.remove(this.profile.steamAccount.personaname);
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
}

//// deleteSteamAccount action

fn: async function (inputs) {
    var steamId = inputs.id;
    await Steam.destroy({id: steamId});
    await User.updateOne({steamAccount: steamId}).set({steamAccount: null});
    // All done.
  }
```

Sadly I'm stuck after try some other method, and need some help to figure out what I miss.

Here follow the code in question, thank you for the time you take to answer my question.

Comment: Lodash handles arrays - your data is no array it seems. Maybe just dereference this.profile.steamAccount = false ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, in deed the problem is here. The answer you gave me just resolve my problem, i was in deed completly missing the fact that i have access to ` this.profile ` changing the code has you suggest solve my issue.

Thank you again.